# How to find polygons with area size between 300 and 500?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, query

I have bunch of polyygons, all with different area-size. I want to find polygons with areasize between 300-500. Normally I would pick out everyone above 300 (query1) and then commit a new query on query1, picking out evryone below 500.

Is there an easier way to do this in either MapInfo or  QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: SQL Select]

in MapInfo you can do it in a single query like the above (change table name and units in the area measurement to suit)

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS, you can use the following in **Select by expression**:

```
$area > 300 and $area < 500
```